# How to send DB Mail for two dynamic queries and two file as a attachement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sendmail

I want to send DB Mail having two queries and send two files as a attachment having result of first query in one file and second in another file.

Below is my code which send only one file as attachment,

```
 DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)= '',
       @sql2 NVARCHAR(max)= '',
     @prefix nvarchar(100),  
     @RefundSubject AS VARCHAR(100)

    set @sql='SET NOCOUNT ON select * from table1 '
    set @sql2='SET NOCOUNT ON select * from table2'

    DECLARE @b NVARCHAR(max)

    declare @prevDate varchar(30)=CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),GETDATE()-1,105)  

    SET @RefundSubject =' Transactions ' + ' ' + 'For Date ' +@prevDate;                                   


    SET @b = '</style><br/>Hi Sir,<br/><br/>Kindly find attached details.<br/><br/>'           

    declare @filenames nvarchar(50)                                                    

    SET @prefix = 'Report.csv'                          

    exec('USE msdb')                                

    EXEC msdb..sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='Mail',                     

        @recipients='mansi07091@gmail.com',  

        @subject = @RefundSubject                             

       ,@body = @b  

       ,@body_format='HTML'                               

       ,@query = @sql          

       ,@attach_query_result_as_file = 1                      

       ,@query_result_separator = '^'                            

       ,@query_result_no_padding = 1                            

       ,@query_result_header = 1                            

      ,@query_attachment_filename =@prefix                            

    SET @sql = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as below

@file_attachments=’D:\temp\blog.csv;D:\temp\sample.csv